# 7 zip- files still zipped will not allow programs(exe) to open

Tags: windows-10, 7-zip

I know with winrar I can run exe files that are zipped to run, but with 7zip it seems like I cannot do that is there a setting that I can change to make it run without unzipping it?

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt it has anything to do with the 7-zip compression program.  When you "run" a program inside of an archive, the compression program decompresses the selected program (just the .exe you selected) to a temporary location and then executes the selected program.  If the selected program is able to run on its own, it will.  However, some programs require more than just the .exe file to run.  That is more than likely the issue you are running into.